# Assessing multicollinearity of factors

Tags: regression, correlation, factor-analysis, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I have a multifactor model (with 7 factors currently) and 754018 observations. In order to check for multicollinearity issues as the model grows I wrote an R script to compute a correlation matrix from the factors (so with 7 factors it's a 7x7 matrix). I then apply the function:

$$\frac{r}{(1-r^2) / (N-2)}$$

where $N = 754018$ and $r$ is the sample correlation in order to get a test statistic according to http://faculty.vassar.edu/lowry/ch4apx.html.

Then I get a corresponding p-value, and display those factor pairs (and their sample correlation) whose correlation p-value is less than $0.05$.

After running this I get 12 pairs displayed! With 7 factors the total number of possible pairs is 21 so this is pretty bad. Out of these 12, however, only 4 of them have correlations above .1 and the rest have sample correlations of around .02 or .01...from a practical standpoint should I worry about any nonzero correlation with very small pvalue (as in all 12 pairs) or only those with small pvalue AND high sample correlation? As in maybe only those 4? If the latter, are there empirical ways of choosing a threshold sample correlation?

Thanks

Comment: Correlations by themselves don't tell us a lot about multicollinearity; hypothesis tests about correlations tell us nothing at all.  What is the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) of the matrix?  What about the [VIFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) in the regression?

Comment: What's your question? Is your multifactor model for prediction or inference? Do you have any predetermined reason to be worried about this?

Comment: @whuber correlation between two independent variables isn't useful for multicollinearity? I thought that's what multicollinearity was all about...and that if two features were too correlated that this would inflate standard errors being it harder to differentiate their effect on the independent? Suppose I find VIFs..then do I have to do this for each factor (removing it one by one) to compare? Could I just look at the adjusted R-squared for every factor thrown in?

Comment: @Adam The multifactor model is for prediction. Doesn't multicollinearity affect the estimation of parameters?

Comment: Palace, your test merely establishes that some correlations are nonzero.  Pairwise correlations will be problematic for regression only when their magnitudes are close to 1, which is not at all the same as being different from 0!  Moreover, p-values are completely meaningless: you're not trying to make inferences about how the independent variables are correlated within a population; all you care about for regression is how the IVs *in your particular sample* happen to be correlated.  The effects of their mutual correlations are better assessed with diagnostics like the VIF.

Comment: I was reading about the VIF. It sounds pretty similar to partial F-testing and adjusted R squared. I'll opt into that instead I guess. Thanks though, and by the way do you know of any good books for this kind of practical topic?

Comment: 1. What whuber said. 2. I'm a bit lost on "I get 12 pairs displayed! With 7 factors the total number of possible pairs is 21 so this is pretty bad."  Why don't you have all pairs displayed? Coding error? Or are you only displaying the ones that are stastically significant?   3. You have 700,000 observations. To me, this makes the issue of a statistical test for r moot and only the magnitude matters. I personally wouldn't worry about a .10 correlation unless there is some theoretical reason why this is key (although I can't think of one).

Comment: Re books: Belsley, Kuh, & Welsch, [Regression Diagnostics.](http://books.google.com/books/about/Regression_diagnostics.html?id=v7GmySJLDVUC)

Comment: @whuber In my attempts to reduce the number of unanswered questions, I came to this one. It seems to me that your comments make up an answer. Do you want to write it? Or should I?

Comment: @Peter I appreciate the invitation.  The question is a little overwhelming because it is begging for an extensive answer covering various points: hypothesis testing of assumptions with large datasets; the relationships between pairwise correlations and multicollinearity; how to analyze multicollinearity in a model matrix *ala* BK&W; the relative unimportance of this question with large datasets; and more.  If you can handle even a small part of that well in a compact answer, then go for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.  Among them are:

Most central, I think, is the relation between correlation and collinearity. You can have very high collinearity without any high correlations. For an intuitive, extreme case, imagine that there are 10 independent variables; nine of them are perfectly orthogonal (within sampling error) and the tenth is the sum of the other nine. You will then have no very high correlation, but perfect collinearity. You can also have sets of IVs that are related to each other.

The key point is that collinearity is a relationship among *sets* of IVs, not necessarily pairs.

A second point relates to hypothesis testing and p values. People who have read my posts know that I am a fairly extreme anti-p-value person, but here, the whole hypothesis testing apparatus is not appropriate.  You have no hypothesis to test. The test that you did tests whether the correlations are significantly different from 0. But .... who cares? First, you have ~750,000 observations. With that data set size, even a tiny correlation will be significantly different from 0, but that won't have any bad effects on a regression. Second, even with a smaller data set, the key question is not whether the correlations are different from 0, but how big the condition indexes are (I prefer these to VIFs, but you can use VIFs if you like).

(As an aside, in Belsley's books he shows that you can have fairly *large* correlations and not have problematic collinearity. I don't have access to his books any more, but I read them for my dissertation).

Third, you say you started with seven factors. You don't describe them. Maybe these are continuous independent variables. But, from my experience, the word "factor" in a context like this either means a) Results of a factor analysis or b) Categorical variables.  If it's a) then, for the most common types of FA, the factors are orthogonal. They can't be collinear.  If b) then I am not sure what you did.

The comments (above) raise some other issues, too, but I think that's enough.

Answer (score -3):

Suppose that we have a matrix X of n observations on k factors.

Suppose that W is the k by k matrix of the eigenvectors of the k by k correlation matrix V of X.

Since V is symmetric and positive definite, all its eigenvalues are real and positive.

Then the n by k matrix P of the principal components of V is such that: $\text{P=XW}$.

So if we regress on P instead of regressing on X, we obtain a vector of k coefficients $\gamma$, say, such that

$$P\gamma=\left(XW\right)\gamma=X\left(W\gamma\right)$$

Since P is orthogonal, the regression on P is well behaved, unless the rank of V is less than k.

But since the factors are multicollinear, $\beta=W\gamma$  is not well defined.

In order to approximate X, we can use the matrix $W_{\left(j\right)}$ of the first j eigenvectors of V, which define the first j columns of P, renamed $P_{\left(j\right)}$.

Since W is orthonormal, we have that $W^{-1}=W^{'}$, so that $X=PW^{'}$. The corresponding approximation for X would be

$$X_{\left(j\right)}=P_{\left(j\right)}W_{\left(j\right)}^{'}$$

This approximation could be such that the k columns of matrix $X_{\left(j\right)}$ are no longer multicollinear.

Accordingly, if we name $\gamma_{\left(j\right)}$ the first j coefficients of the vector $\gamma$, we have that

$$P_{\left(j\right)}\gamma_{\left(j\right)}=\left(X_{\left(j\right)}W_{\left(j\right)}\right)\gamma_{\left(j\right)}=X_{\left(j\right)}\left(W_{\left(j\right)}\gamma_{\left(j\right)}\right)$$

Thus, if we define $\beta_{\left(j\right)}=W_{\left(j\right)}\gamma_{\left(j\right)}$, we have a vector of k well behaved coefficients, in principle.

The proportion of the variance of X explained by the first j eigenvectors of V is given by the proportion of the cumulative sum of the corresponding eigenvalues of V to the sum of all eigenvalues of V. Since a few of the largest eigenvalues of V form the largest proportion of the sum of all eigenvalues of V when multicollinearity is a problem, we must choose the j eigenvectors corresponding to the largest j eigenvalues of V to approximate X.

Comment: (The $\TeX$ will work much better when delimited with dollar signs ($).) You describe "PCA regression," but I have some doubts about its applicability, in particular concerning the last paragraph.  What matters for regression are the partial correlations between the independent variables and the dependent variable.  It is possible--even likely--that some of the principal components with *small* eigenvalues may be much better correlated with the dependent variable than some of the PCs with *larger* EVs.  Thus, no criterion based solely on the sizes of the EVs can be generally appropriate.